# Deleted selected rows from JQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How do I delete my selected rows from datatables that use a local array for data? This is how I initialised my table:

```
    var selected = Array();
    var dataSet = [];
    var rowItem = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $("#table").DataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "filter":false,
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": " Search"
            },
            "select": {
                "style": 'multi'
            },
            "ordering": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "columns": [
               { "title": "Name"},
            ],
            "responsive": true,
            "processing":true,
        }).columns.adjust()
        .responsive.recalc();
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
```

This is how I'm trying to delete the selected rows from my tables:

```
      $("#roleSection").on("click","#removeRole",function (e) {
            selected = table.rows('.selected').data().toArray();
            console.log(selected);
            $.each(selected, function (id, value) {
                console.log(value);
                dataSet.splice($.inArray(value, dataSet), 1);
                table.row(selected).remove().draw();
            });
            console.log(dataSet);
            return false;
        });
```

For some reason the items that are not deleted are being deleted and the table does not get updated at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I think you can find your answer over [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove())

- Basically, you have to change your line `selected = table.rows('.selected').data().toArray();` to `table.rows( '.selected' ).remove().draw();`
- And remove the additional code.
- You also don't have to worry about looping through the list because `table.rows('.selected')` gets all the rows with the class selected and then `remove()` deletes them all for you.

### Edit: If the dataSet is not updated automatically, then I think this might answer your second query

```
$("#delete").on("click", function (e) {
  let newDataSet = [];
  table.rows( '.selected' ).remove().draw();
  table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    let row = this;
    newDataSet.push(row.data());
  });
  dataSet = newDataSet;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. How do I delete my items from my array also?

Comment: @JianYA Check the edited answer. I think that might do it.